# Is there any python str() equivalent with utf-8 encoding?

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8

I have a function that is suposed to print a variable in the screen of a python program.
Normally, I do:

```
mystring = str(variable)
```

Then I print mystring in the screen of the program with its command:

```
g.es(mystring)
```

I don't know what the variable is going to be, and that's why I must do str(variable) first.
It can be a list, a dict,integer, anything.

This was working perfectly until I used some non ascii character inside myvalue.
In this case, the function shows the following unicode encode error:

```
UnicodeencodeError: 'ascii' codec cant decode character ...
```

If I use:

```
mystring = unicode(variable,utf-8)
```

Wont work because the variable can be a list, and unicode() only accepts strings. And I cant do str(variable) for obvious reasons.

Is there any function that will transform any variable using utf-8 or should I create a specific one for this purpose?
Thank you!

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: What OS? Python version? Also, what is `g.es(...)`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay: python 2.7, g.es() is a function inside the program that will print a string on its screen. But Martijn accurately pinpoints the issue. Thank you all very much, I really appreciate your answers and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to test for the type, I am afraid:

```
def to_utf8_string(val):
    if not isinstance(val, basestring):
        return str(val)
    if not isinstance(val, str):
        val = val.encode('utf8')
    return val
```

This is pretty much what the `print()` command does, albeit that it detects what encoding to use from the `sys.stdout` stream before encoding.

Comment: The real problem is what to do if `val` is already a `str`, but it's in some other encoding. (And the solution, of course, is documentation telling the person using your function not to do that.)

Comment: @Wooble: that's a whole other kettle of fish; it depends on what `g.es()` does to the string. For example, `print()` just echos the byte string to `sys.stdout()` and it depends on the terminal what happens in that case.

Comment: After replacing str() with this function, Its producting some unexpected "None" where str() did not. I will try to pinpoint where this is happening and post the update on how to avoid that.

Comment: @Iwantbadges: yes, sorry; if `val` is already a `str` value, it wasn't being returned. Corrected.